# Can not get Roslyn to work with .NET 5 project

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, .net-5, roslyn-code-analysis

After spending way too much time, I still can't make Roslyn to load simple C# project.
Project source:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="16.11.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.11.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.11.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Code that is trying to load:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace Metrics5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            
            workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
            var currentProject = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(@"C:\work\Metrics5\Metrics5.csproj").Result;
            var diagnostics = workspace.Diagnostics;
                
            foreach(var diagnostic in diagnostics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It says:

> Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\work\Metrics5\Metrics5.csproj' with message: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  C:\work\Metrics5\Metrics5.csproj

After I add `MSBuildSDKsPath` as environment value `MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks` it seems to pass that step and stuck in another:

> Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\work\Metrics5\Metrics5.csproj' with message: The imported project "C:\work\Metrics5\bin\Debug\net5.0\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import de
> claration "C:\work\Metrics5\bin\Debug\net5.0\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props

And from here I'm not sure how to proceed, am I missing some nuget package?
Do I need to install additionally something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add reference to `Microsoft.Build.Locator`

I used the next packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.11.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then register the instance of MSBuild using MSBuildLocator:

```
//add this line before using MSBuildWorkspace
MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();  //select the recent SDK
using var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
```

You Can control the version of MsBuild:

```
var visualStudioInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances();
//select NET5, or whatever by modifying Version.Major 
var instance = visualStudioInstances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Version.Major.ToString() == "5");
MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks